# What mitigations exist for AMD vulnerability CVE-2023-20593 Zenbleed?

Tags: amd, speculative-execution

I recently read that in the never ending series of speculative-execution flaws, unintended data written to extended registers ends up [making secrets readable across privilege boundaries](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2023-20593) on AMD Zen 2 CPUs. This sounds like something I do not want my processes (or KVM guests) to do against each other.

AMD has [acknowledged the problem](https://www.amd.com/en/resources/product-security/bulletin/amd-sb-7008.html) but offers no updates or mitigations except for 17h/31h (EPYC 7002 series) processors.

Tavis Ormandy (Google) who discovered the flaw [suggests](https://lock.cmpxchg8b.com/zenbleed.html#solution) to flip a [not exactly self-explanatory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76763069/amd-de-cfg9-documentation) MSR bit `DE_CFG[9]`, which I *speculate* might force some sort of serialization guarantee to eliminate the described flaw and/or exploitation path.

For other affected CPUs, such as Ryzen 4000 series, is there anything else one can do, except for:

- wait for AMD to release microcode ("Target Dec 2023" does not sound like  soon)
- stop using such CPU for anything that requires privilege separation (expensive)

Specifically, I wonder if reconfiguring the scheduler could secure a Linux system against both this sort of information disclosure and yet-to-be-discovered variants by eliminating at least the obvious the scenario where the register contains data from different processes. I imagine just like previous speculative execution bugs, given one example and detection method, additional security-relevant problems following that pattern are going to be discovered.

Comment: With [newer information emerging](https://comsec.ethz.ch/research/microarch/), the background of not properly documenting mitigation strategies might be that additional, at that time still embargoed, branch-prediction related flaws [cannot be mitigated without microcode changes either](https://www.amd.com/en/resources/product-security/bulletin/amd-sb-7005.html).